# Article usage when talking generally (not about specific things)

Tags: articles

I have a question about article usage. I have two sentences and I'm struggling with the articles in the second sentence:

> There may be invoices on each table.
> When (?) invoices lying on (?) table disappear, it's a problem.

I would guess the invoices and a table. My reasoning is that I'm not talking about specific table so it should be indefinite article. But definite article for invoices because we talk about specific invoices on that table.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to say "When invoices disappear..."? If it's not a case of disappearing from a particular table, why bother mentioning a table at all?

Comment: Let's assume that it's a problem only if invoices disappear from table and it's fine if they disappear from vault.

Comment: I would say _lying on tables_, as there is more than one.

Comment: "When invoices disappear" works, but you're being too literal when you say the invoices aren't specific. They are any that lived on tables and walked away.

Comment: Is it a problem when the invoices on *both* tables disappear? Or is it a problem if the invoices on *either* table disappear?

Comment: @alphabet If the first were intended, it would have to say "tables" (plural).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

> When the invoices lying on a table disappear, it's a problem.

You can't use "an invoices" because "invoices" is plural and "an" can only be used before a singular noun.

You can't use "the table" because that refers to a specific table, and no such table has been indicated yet. "a table" means any one of the tables.